# typedef error on C++ Integer type defines

Tags: c++, qt, typedef

So I've started renaming types to get more deep into things. Here is the section of code that is causing the problem:

```
#if COMPILER != COMPILER_GNU
typedef signed __int64 int64;
typedef signed __int32 int32;
typedef signed __int16 int16;
typedef signed __int8 int8;

typedef unsigned __int64 uint64;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32;
typedef unsigned __int16 uint16;
typedef unsigned __int8 uint8;
#else

typedef int64_t int64;
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef int16_t int16;
typedef int8_t int8;
typedef uint64_t uint64;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef uint16_t uint16;
typedef uint8_t uint8;
#endif
```

The code inside the else loop:

```
typedef int64_t int64;
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef int16_t int16;
typedef int8_t int8;
typedef uint64_t uint64;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef uint16_t uint16;
typedef uint8_t uint8;
#endif
```

Makes QT throw an error while compiling saying they do not name a type, and whenever I use one of these it throws an error saying they do not name a type. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you including `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>` first?

Comment: "So I've started renaming types to get more deep into things" - seems you got deep into trouble. Seriously, just use `<cstdint>`.